# Limit woocommerce basket size

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a snipped below that restricts woocommerce orders to 5 items. When they try go through checkout with more than 5 items it pops up a message telling them that and they then have to remove items. What I am wondering is if there is a way so that they can't add more than 5 items to the basket?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'set_max_num_products' );
function set_max_num_products() {
// Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Set the max number of products before checking out
    $max_num_products = 5;
    // Get the Cart's total number of products
    $cart_num_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;

    // A max of 5 products is required before checking out.
    if( $cart_num_products > $max_num_products ) {
        // Display our error message
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A maxiumum of %s samples are allowed per order. Your cart currently contains %s.</strong>',
            $max_num_products,
            $cart_num_products ),
        'error' );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every product must be validated before it can be added to the cart. You can modify the validation status via the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter and thus control whether it is or is not added to the cart.

```
function so_33134668_product_validation( $valid, $product_id, $quantity ){
    // Set the max number of products before checking out
    $max_num_products = 5;
    // Get the Cart's total number of products
    $cart_num_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;

    $future_quantity_in_cart = $cart_num_products + $quantity;

    // More than 5 products in the cart is not allowed
    if( $future_quantity_in_cart > $max_num_products ) {
        // Display our error message
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A maxiumum of %s samples are allowed per order. Your cart currently contains %s.</strong>',
            $max_num_products,
            $cart_num_products ),
        'error' );
        $valid = false; // don't add the new product to the cart
    }
    return $valid;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_33134668_product_validation', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Just want to know can we use `$product_id where $product_id = (int) ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_GET['add-to-cart'] ) ? apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_GET['add-to-cart'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['add-to-cart'] ) ) ;`   the just added product and limit its quantity ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: If we can retrieve the product just added to cart and its quantity to compare with cart quantity and let the customer know why he can not add more product . this is what I am asking .

Comment: That's what I think i have done with the `$future_quantity_in_cart` variable. Checking the quantity attempting to add to the cart ( `$quantity`) and adding it to the current quantity of items in the cart (`$cart_num_products`)

Comment: How you are retrieving the $quantity   ? Is it within the scope of `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook ?

Comment: Yes, it is the 3rd parameter.

Comment: Thank you @helgatheviking!! Works a treat, just what I was trying to achieve. Sorry for not replying sooner I forgot to check back here for replies.

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for returning and marking the answer as complete.